# In a ReactiveUI/WPF view model, what is the right way to schedule OAPHs on observables filled by other threads?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, reactiveui, reactivex

I have ReactiveUI viewmodels, constructed in a WPF app's start-up thread, where properties are `ObservableAsPropertyHelper`-backed views onto observables being fed by events from a separate `Task` thread.  What is the right way to set up the OAPHs' schedulers to avoid threading issues while maintaining testability, not pushing too much into the UI thread, and not overly complicating the viewmodels?

To give more detail: I've recently picked up [ReactiveUI](https://reactiveui.net/) as a framework for building MVVM glue code in a .NET Core 3 WPF side project I've been working on.  It's a client for a client/server audio playback system, and most of the UI's updates come from `IObservable`s that are ultimately attached to events (using `FromEventPattern`) that are triggered in a reader `Task` spinning over a TCP connection.  (Whether or not this is a good idea, I'll probably leave for another question.)

My ViewModels tend to do this:

- Accept one of the above `IObservable`s in the constructor;
- Bind a few LINQ transformations of the observable to properties using an `ObservableAsPropertyHelper`, through `.ToProperty`;
- Bind a few more projections of those properties using a combination of `.WhenAnyValue` and `.ToProperty`.

As I haven't bought into the ReactiveUI binding and activation system, the ViewModels get constructed (I believe) on the same thread as `App.xaml`'s code-behind, and all of their OAPHs get initialised in the constructor.  All accesses to the ViewModel properties are happening through one-way XAML bindings.

Just to clarify, the view models are in one project with `ReactiveUI` but *not* `ReactiveUI.WPF` etc. installed; the WPF app itself *does* have `ReactiveUI.WPF` installed.

I've tried a few different approaches to feeding schedulers to the `ToProperty` calls and their providing schedulers:

1. Not overriding any schedulers at all.  At first, I thought this would be correct, as [the documentation on `ObservableAsPropertyHelper`](https://reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/observable-as-property-helper/) doesn't mention any overrides.  This fails with 'can't modify object because this isn't the thread that created it' type exceptions, presumably because the property change notifications are happening on the reader `Task` thread.
2. Overriding the scheduler of OAPHs attaching to the reader `Task`'s observable with `scheduler: RxApp.MainThreadScheduler` in its `ToProperty`, after reading in various places that [OAPHs use the current thread's scheduler by default.](https://reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/testing/).  This fixed the crashing exceptions, but, when I tried to unit-test the view model, I started getting odd scheduling Heisenbugs where changes fed through the server-update observable weren't propagating through to `WhenAnyValue` derived properties.
3. Overriding the scheduler of the other OAPHs too, which didn't help (but maybe perturbed the failures a little).  At this stage, I was confused, because [the ReactiveUI documentation suggests that `RxApp.MainThreadScheduler` should be immediate when it detects unit tests](https://reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/scheduling/), and so everything should be on the same thread and (hopefully) operating sequentially.
4. Pushing in the `scheduler` in the constructor of the viewmodel ([as per this constructor from someone else's project](https://github.com/kentcb/WorkoutWotch/blob/master/Src/WorkoutWotch.ViewModels/ExerciseProgramViewModel.cs#L46-L207)), and specifically setting it to `Immediate` in the unit test (and `RxApp.MainThreadScheduler` elsewhere).

Here is a somewhat simplified version of the code I've been working with, after step 4:

```cs
// Represents the 'play/pause/stop' controls on an audio playback UI.
// The UI connects through an IObservable to a message feed coming from
// a playback server.
public class PlayerTransportViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
    // Holds the current 'state' of the audio being played (play/pause/stop). 
    private readonly ObservableAsPropertyHelper<PlaybackState> _state;
    public PlaybackState State => _state.Value;

    // For the view's convenience, we break out 'state' into three separate Booleans:
    private readonly ObservableAsPropertyHelper<bool> _isPlaying;
    private readonly ObservableAsPropertyHelper<bool> _isPaused;
    private readonly ObservableAsPropertyHelper<bool> _isStopped;
    public bool IsPlaying => _isPlaying.Value;
    // ... and so on for _isPaused and _isStopped.

    // The constructor then takes an observable over some raw feed of server messages.
    public PlayerTransportViewModel(IObservable<PlaybackEvent> events, IScheduler? scheduler)
    {
        // This glue *shouldn't* introduce asynchronicity into the observable.
        var states = SomeLinqGlueSelectingPlaybackStatesFrom(events);
        // This binding directly takes in an observable fed by a message decoding thread.
        // Is the explicit scheduler needed?
        _state = states.ToProperty(this, x => x.State, PlaybackState.Stopped, scheduler: scheduler);

        // These bindings are derived from State by WhenAny.
        // Is the explicit scheduler needed?
        _isPlaying = this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.State, x => x == PlaybackState.Playing).ToProperty(this, x => x.IsPlaying, scheduler: scheduler);
        // ... and so on for _isPaused and _isStopped.
    }
}
```

This code seems to work fine now, but I feel like I've cargo culted without fully understanding what the correct minimal amount of scheduler interference should be, or even whether I'm just patching over problems elsewhere in the program.  (I'm having some strange Heisenbug instances with other parts of the same project, but I haven't pinned them down to askable questions yet, so this is me starting with the fundamental gap in my knowledge).